# matches function argument codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In the form validation the current password must match the password that i logged in.If the current password that i introduce matches the password that i use to log in i can change my it. But it doesn't work, i can put any password in my current password field. My question is how to put in matches function the password that i use to log in. (The password that i use to log is stored into a session).

```
function edit_info()

{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname2','FirstName','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname2','LastName','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('current_password','Current Password','trim|required|matches(password)');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password3','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->edit();  
    }
    else
    {   

        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        if($this->membership_model->edit_member())
        {
            $data['main_content']='edit_successful';
            $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('main_menu'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an callback to a function inside the controller.

```
// call function to check
$this->form_validation->set_rules('current_password','Current Password','trim|required|callback_password_check');

// do your check and return false or true
public function password_check($str){

}
```

Go to: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks